# Stripe Ruby - Find existing customer by ID and add a plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

So the Stripe docs say:

> Once you've created a customer, you should store its id in your own database so you can refer to it later when communicating with stripe.

Okay, easy enough. My question is: how do I find a customer by their ID?
**UPDATE** like this:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(id)
```

When I sign up a new customer for one of my services I create a new Stripe `Customer`, but if they are an existing customer I'd like to use their existing account and simply add a plan. How do I find them and add a new plan? I looked through the docs and the ruby gem but couldn't figure it out. Help please? Here's the method in question.

```
def social_signup
    token = params[:stripe_token]
    if current_vendor.stripe_id == nil
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :card => token,
            :plan => 'social',
            :email => current_vendor.email
        )

        current_vendor.update_attributes(stripe_id: customer.id)
    else
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_vendor.stripe_id)
        # bill the customer's existing account for the added subscription
    end

    redirect_to :somewhere
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a customer:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_vendor.stripe_id) # pass in the persisted ID
```

Create a new subscription to a plan:

```
customer.subscriptions.create(plan: "social")
```

The docs are pretty thorough, just had to dig through and find the specifics. Incidentally, adding multiple subscriptions for a single customer was a feature that Stripe [added in February of this year](https://stripe.com/blog/multiple-subscriptions).

Comment: In my case, I use ```current_user.stripe_id``` and it works. Rails does not understand what ```current_vendor``` is.

Comment: @QuyLe yes, you should use the object/field where the stripe id is stored. `current_vendor` was an example from the app I was working on -- yours will likely be different.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is how you create a plan now that you have your customer.

```
Stripe::Customer.create({
    :card => customer.id,
    :plan => your_plan,
    }, access_token
  )
```

Comment: That still calls create on `Stripe::Customer`, creating a new customer unfortunately. I found the answer to this, check below. Also, `:card` should be keyed to the token created by `Stripe.js`, not the customer id.